# Nested Loop Iteration Count

Tags: loops, count

Sorry if I'm re-asking a previous question but I can't quite find a concrete answer to this question. How can I make a formula for nested for loop iterations besides basic ones like:

```
for (int i =0; i < N; i++)
```

I get the basic concept of count iterations of basic loops:

```
for (int i =0; i < N; i++)
```

The boolean condition is equal to some variable (for instance N) then is subtracted from the initial variable (for instance i) then is divided by the number of loops nested (in this case 1 since it is not nested). So the number of iterations for this loop would be:

```
(N - i) / 1
```

For example, for finding the iterations of nested loops this would be repeated down the loops until you make it to the innermost loop then you multiple all the loops for the iteration count.

I just don't understand more complicated loops with different increment conditions such as multiplication or division. Specifically how I can figure out how many times this loop iterates:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i *= 2)
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
```

I know this has to do something with summation unfortunately I'm not seeing the connection. Any resources or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure where division or subtraction comes into play for any of these loops.

Comment: Where i or j is incremented. The update/increment part of the for loop.

Comment: but those add/increment or multiply.  I just don't understand your statement that starts with "The boolean condition...".

Comment: In that part I am saying I understand the loop yields N (initial variable) - i (0 in this case) / 1 (The loop # in a nested loop in this case 1 since it isn't nested in any other loop). The next two sentences is where my actual question is. I can't just repeat the process of the sentences above as the two nested loops aren't N / 1 iterations. Why? because of the *= increment part of the loop. So how do I figure out a formula for iterations?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're reading the loop syntax wrong?

Try reading them aloud, like this:

for this loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i *= 2)
```

The loop syntax reads:

> Starting from One, keep looping while i is less than one thousand - and each time around the loop, multiply i by two.

So, i starts at one, and gets multiplied by two each time around the loop - i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16.... This carries on until it gets to one thousand (or over it) - and the loop stops.

and for this loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
```

the loop syntax says:

> Starting at zero, keep looping while j is less than one thousand - and each time around the loop, add one to j.

For nested loops, there is no difference, except that for each time around the outer loop, the whole inner loop runs to completion.

I find that reading things aloud - or sounding them out in your head - can really help to make sense of them.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, my question though is how do I figure out how many times it iterates before the loop terminates without running the programming or manually counting the iterations to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Just work out how many times each one loops.  This is easy because they are not co-dependent (*ie* the `j` loop does not rely on `i`).

- The `i` loop goes `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., 512`.  Since it must be less than 1000, it will stop when it reaches 1024.  That's a total of 10 iterations.  Count them by hand, or calculate `log2(1024)`.
- The `j` loop goes `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 999`.  That's a total of 1000 iterations.

So you have an inner loop of 1000 iterations that is repeated 10 times by the outer loop.  That's a total of 10,000 iterations.

Comment: How would I do this for an arbitrary number? Counting iterations for i < 10 * 10^34 would definitely take longer. My question is what is the formula for counting those iterations.

Comment: Do you mean in the case where `i` starts at 1 and is repeatedly multiplied by `X`?  You just take the upper bound of the log (base-X) of the terminating condition.  So if it's `(i=1; i<2160872398; i*=X)`, you find `ceil(log(2160872398) / log(X))`.  That's the theory, but you might want to implement an integer-based log function, because floating-point rounding errors will bite you here.

Comment: Thank you. So the formula for my original question I'm assuming is: (ceil(log(N - 1, base: increment-value)) * (N / 2)

Comment: I can't tell you without seeing code for what you're talking about.  If you're talking about that piece in the middle of your question, vaguely describing some looping scenario in words, I suggest you put it in code.  If you're referring to the last code block and using `N` instead of 1000, then I would say no - your assumption does not look correct.

Comment: Yes, I'm implying the amount of times the second loop is ran/iterated with N = 1000. I am wrong the equation seems to be coming out to: (ceil(log(N - 1, base: increment-value)) * N but I don't understand why when the second loop should be N / 2 since it is the second loop.

Comment: It has nothing to do with it being the second loop.  You don't divide by two.  The outer loop has `log2(N)` iterations, the inner loop has `N` iterations.  The inner loop of `N` iterations is therefore repeated `log2(N)` times, so you have a total of `N * log2(N)` iterations.